# Adding and getting values of NSMutableDictionary not working

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to do some complex stuff, but when I add to an nsmutabledictionary and try to get values from it, it's simply returning nothing and not printing anything when I try to print what it returns. I can't even get the following to print anything in an ibaction, even though the action is being triggered.  Could you like me know if I'm doing anything wrong and what it is? Thanks!

Sample code of super simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
NSMutableDictionary *test;
[test setObject:@"ValueIWantToGet" forKey:@"KeyIAmSetting"];
NSLog([test objectForKey:@"KeyIAmSetting"]); //Should print "ValueIWantToGet", right?
```

Comment: You can't work on an object unless you initialize it first.

Comment: But when I do the alloc init thing, it crashes and says it's disabled due to ARC?

Comment: Never use `NSLog` without a literal format string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `test` variable is not initialized. Do this instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *test = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

or

```
NSMutableDictionary *test = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

In Objective-C all objects are manipulated through pointers. Hence the asterisks in declarations in front of variable names. When you do not assign anything to a pointer, its value remains uninitialized, so any reference to it is undefined behavior. In situations when the value happens to be `nil`, however, you would not see a crash, because Objective-C allows sending messages to `nil` (they have no effect).

> I'm making a property of an `NSMutableDictionary`, so how should I initialized it if it's a property?

Properties should be initialized in the initializer of your class, for example

```
-(instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _test = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I'm making a property of an nsmutabledictionary, so how should I initialize it if it's a property?